# flexslide animation using jquery and html

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I wrote my animation code like below but it doesn't work (I've added *jquery*(jquery-1.9.1.js) and *flexslider*(jquery.flexslider-min.js) files to my project). Hav u any ideas?

**Html code**

```
<div class="slider">
<ul class="slides">

    <li>
        <img src="images/demo_image_26.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="slider-caption-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-caption">
                <p class="colour-caption medium-caption">100% Responsive &amp; Mobile Ready</p>
                <div class="clearboth"></div>
                <p class="dark-caption large-caption">Room Availability Checker and Booking</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="images/demo_image_06.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="slider-caption-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-caption">
                <p class="colour-caption medium-caption">5 Fantastic Home Pages to Choose From</p>
                <div class="clearboth"></div>
                <p class="dark-caption large-caption">Customer Testimonials &amp; Event Management</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="images/demo_image_25.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="slider-caption-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-caption">
                <p class="colour-caption medium-caption">Fully Customizable Colour Scheme</p>
                <div class="clearboth"></div>
                <p class="dark-caption large-caption">4 Pre Configured Colour Schemes Available</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**JS code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.slider').flexslider({
    slideshow: true
 });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please show your script tags order

Comment: I dont understand which script tags order you said

Comment: show me your head part of your html

Comment: http://hotelsmith.az/ you can see my code in this web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the flexsider CSS file. I think you have missed in your code. I have created one fiddle with your code and I copied flexsider javascript and CSS file from your site. After that it was working fine with the misalignments. [**Check My Fiddle Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/DTFhY/1/)

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.slider').flexslider({
  slideshow: true,
  slideshowSpeed: 2000
  });
});
```